# Llenar campo SELECT HTML a partir de consulta

Tags: php, html, mysql

un saludo cordial.

Tengo un formulario HTML para EDITAR un listado de datos, en un CRUD.

Estoy haciendo la consulta a la base de datos para EDITAR cada uno de los registros. Así, por ejemplo los campos simples de texto los estoy capturando para editar de esta manera:

```
<input type="text" id="e_direccion" name="e_direccion" value = "<?php echo $fila['e_direccion']; ?>"><br>
```

Pero a la hora de EDITAR un campo SELECT tengo dificultades, cuando ya la base de datos tiene los datos registrados, y estos fueron alimentados por un select, como hago para consultar esos datos y modificarlos por medio de otro select?

En los formularios de CREAR tengo varios select, uno de ellos por ejemplo lo ingreso así:

```
<select name="e_acudiente">
    <option>Acudiente</option>
    <?php
        include ("conexion.php");
        $consulta = "SELECT * from acudientes";
        $resultados = $conexion->query ($consulta);
        if ($conexion->errno) {
            die ($conexion->error);
        }
        while ($fila=$resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
            $fullname = $fila['a_nombres'] ." / " . $fila['a_apellidos'];
            echo "<option value='". $fila['a_id'] ."'>". $fullname ."</option>";
        }                      
    ?>
</select><br>
```

El otro lo ingreso así:

```
<select name = "e_acudiente_parentesco">
    <option>Parentesco</option>
    <option>Mama</option>
    <option>Papa</option>
    <option>Hermano</option>
    <option>Tio</option>
    <option>Abuelo</option>
    <option>Otro</option>
</select><br>
```

Como puedo capturar estos datos en el formulario EDITAR que ya fueron ingresados a través del formulario CREAR???

Juan Carlos M.

Comment: para cambiar el dato del `select` tendrias que `javascript` con el metodo `onload` par apoder cambiar su valor, en caso de ser un `select`, pero si tienes de 2 a mas y estos dependientes entre ellos mejor usa `AJAX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder actualizar el componente Select debes utilizar jQuery. Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo: Lo que hace el código, busca la opción con la clase `editable` y muestra un `textbox` con el valor seleccionado, lo modificas y automáticamente se actualiza el select.

**HTML**

```
<select id="test" class="form-control">
   <option class="" value="">...</option>
   <option class="editable" value="Valor1">Valor1</option>
</select>
<input class="editOption" id="test1">
```

**PHP**

```
$idAcudienteParentezco = $fila['id_parentezco']; // Suponiendo que obtienes el id del parentezco
//Ahora debes comparar ese id con los id de tu select
<select name = "e_acudiente_parentesco">
    <option>Parentesco</option>
    <option <?php if ($idAcudienteParentezco == 1) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Mama</option> //Comparas si el id coincide entonces seleccionas este valor
    <option>Papa</option>
    <option>Hermano</option>
    <option>Tio</option>
    <option>Abuelo</option>
    <option>Otro</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var initialText = $('.editable').val();
    $('.editOption').val(initialText);

    $('#test').change(function(){
        var selected = $('option:selected', this).attr('class');
        var optionText = $('.editable').text();

        if(selected == "editable") {
              $('.editOption').show();


              $('.editOption').keyup(function(){
                  var editText = $('.editOption').val();
                  $('.editable').val(editText);
                  $('.editable').html(editText);
              });
        } else {
            $('.editOption').hide();
        }
});


});
```

De igual manera te dejo el código en JSFiddle para que revises el funcionamiento. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wgmoqyae/)

Comment: Hola Eric... creo que no me expliqué, el select se debe alimentar desde la base de datos del registro seleccionado... Por ejemplo, tengo una tabla estudiantes, uno de los campos hace referencia al acudiente, el select ya se está alimentando desde la tabla acudientes, pero yo quiero que salga seleccionado el acudiente del estudiante que ya se había ingresado.

Comment: Oh! En la pregunta inicial dice otra cosa "Editar un Campo Select". Puedes adjuntar en la pregunta la forma en cómo llenas el select. Ahora si entendí lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Hola Eric

Ya edito la pregunta

Comment: Edite la respuesta con el if en el select para que lo selecciones. Hice una línea de ejemplo para que no se vuelva confuso el código. Si tu select es dinámico funcionaría de la misma manera.

Comment: Excelente Eric, con el IF dentro del SELECT pude trabajar, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.